# Why do we use capital letter in this sentence?

Tags: word-usage, usage, sentence-usage

I am not too sure why we use capital letter with the word ‘Site’

here is the context
The Kellers’ caravan is on Site 24.

I did some google research but I did not find anything!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Names of places or locations within a zone, area, building, etc, are often capitalised: Site 24, Room 46, Building 3. It is not compulsory.